# String filter andset permission using VB script

Tags: vbscript

Please help me with 2 things.

I.
When execute this script, Folders are creating like this eg :  "CN=Astra,OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,DC=ddd,DC=com"
but I need to create folder with Astra (CN) only.

Code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim objFSO, objFolder

Set objGroup = GetObject _
("LDAP://cn=UserCreation,ou=aaa,ou=bbb,ou=ccc,dc=ddd,dc=com")
objGroup.GetInfo

arrMemberOf = objGroup.GetEx("member")


For Each strMember in arrMemberOf

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strMember)

Next
```

II. Please help me to set user permission to respective folders. 
   Users are getting from AD group.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sFilterString = "CN=Astra,OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,DC=ddd,DC=com"

'here we break the string into an array of values:
'  aJustCN(0) = "CN=Astra"
'  aJustCN(1) = "OU=aaa"
'  aJustCN(2) = "OU=bbb"
'  ...
'  aJustCN(5) = "OU=com"
aJustCN = Split(sFilterString)


'Here we just truncate the CN= from the string
sJustCN = Replace(aJustCN(0),"CN=","")

'This will return "Astra"
Wscript.Echo sJustCN
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for ur help.. I'm getting o/p:Astra,OU=aaa,OU=bbb,OU=ccc,DC=ddd,DC=com when I executed script and is it possible set dynamic for sFilterString

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you need more help, post more code.

Comment: Good to hear. Most people say thanks by accepting the answer.